# How to pass HTTP post parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In my asp.net application one webpage page_load event

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string data = string.Empty;

            // Determine if session has Single Sign On credentials
            if (Request.Form["Rams"] != null)
            {
                data = RamsLogin();
            }
```

I would like to debug this page from outside the applicaton, How to pass Rams parameter via HTTP post to execute the RamsLogin() method?

Comment: When you will have any value in Request.Form["samlResponse"] then. Also check whether you have kept the code in IsPostBack validation block

Answer (score 1):

The `Page_Load` event runs every time the page loads. In your case, the `SAMLlogin()` method will execute whenever a client submit a `POST` request and inform some value into the `samlResponse` variable.

That request is usually made using HTML `<form method="POST">` and the `samlResponse` variable would be an `INPUT`, `SELECT` or `TEXTAREA` element with the `name="samlResponse"` attribute.

I say *usually* because a program can simulate the same behavior without using any HTML at all.

Comment: Thanks for your response, how the client submit a post request ? they will submit a post request via url or something else ?

Comment: The client is usually a web browser and submit the request as a button click; you can also craft a request and send it directly through HTTP, but I have a feeling this isn't your _actual_ problem.